# Get value of td of table using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to get the value of a `<td>`. I am populating the table from a database, and I can't get the value of a specific field using it's name because the rows are looped and if I use the name, I get the value of that field from the first row. So for that, I wrote my js like this:

```
function searchcatg(el2){
    var catel = $(el2);
    var searchTxt = catel.val();
    //var brandval = $("input[name='brandid']").val();
    var brandval = $(el2).closest("tr").find('td:eq(7)').text();
    alert(brandval);
    $.post("search-cat-brand-vw.php", {searchVal: searchTxt, brand:brandval})
    .done(function(catglist) {

        $("#catglist").html(catglist);
    });

}
```

I get the first value correctly, but the value `brandval` doesn't properly show up. On the alert box it shows some unreadable characters and in the php I post to, it gets a blank. This is how the `brandid` field looks like

```
<td><input type="text" name="brandid" value="<?php echo $brandid; ?>" list="brandlist" id="output" onkeyup="searchbrand(this)" >
        <datalist id="brandlist" name="taskoptionbrand">
                <option> </option>
        </datalist> </td>
```

using `.val()` in the `var brandval` says that it's undefined. What do I do?

Comment: I am not sure what value you are searching for, but change `searchbrand(this)` to `searchbrand(this.value)`

Comment: you may need to change to `$(el2).closest("tr").find('td:eq(7) input').val();`

Comment: @FrayneKonok, that did it! If you can post this as an answer, I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TD` never contain any value, so you can't use the `val()` or `value` in it. You need to find the input box into the `TD` and then use the `val()`.

As i comment it out, you need to change in your function `searchcatg`. Search for the replacement.

**From**

```
$(el2).closest("tr").find('td:eq(7)').text();
```

**TO**

```
$(el2).closest("tr").find('td:eq(7) input').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
var brandval = $('input[name="brandid"]').val();
```

instead of this:

```
var brandval = $(el2).closest("tr").find('td:eq(7)').text();
```

Comment: I already said that doing so works only for the first line only.

Comment: use .each() function to get all value;